# How to convert pdf table to excel without messed up columns?

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have a pdf file with tables that I attached below and I am trying to convert it to Excel tables. I first saved the pdf as html and use import html in Excel to import the table. However some columns are not align. For example, "FROM" should be on top of "1", "TO" should be on top of "2", "FIELD" should be on top of "S0CCO". But you can see that they are a little messed up in Excel.

This is just an example and I have pdf with huge amount of tables like this so I can't manually adjust everything. So I have several questions:

1. Any way to adjust this so all the columns are automatically in right places?
2. Is there any other way to convert a pdf file with a lot of tables like this table into Excel with right columns?
3. This is irrelevant but I tried to use Excel formula =importhtml(url,"table",index) to convert this table. Can anyone explain this formula's meaning to me? How can I tell the second part of the formula is table or list? and what does index mean?

Thank you very much!

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Comment: can you save the pdf file as text?

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF file is definitely a table rather than an image of a table, then I would use Word to open the file and extract the data from the Word File to excel.  You should also be able to check that the values line up properly in the table - if not then the error lies with the original PDF creation, not what you are extracting.

I only have Office XP available right now so this code isn't tested, but something along these lines should work in newer versions.
Basically it will:
Ask what Word or PDF file you want tables extracted from
 - You select the file
It will paste the document contents to sheet1 (you can remove this)
It will create a new worksheet and extract the table contents cell by cell
Repeating for each table in the Document
(Each table in the document will therefore be on a separate worksheet)

```
Sub ImportPDFTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim wrd As Object
Dim ApplicationIsRunning As Object
Dim IsWordRunning As Boolean
Dim TableNo As Integer
Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Integer, iCount As Integer

    wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("PDF files,*.pdf,Word files,*.doc*", , _
    "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

    If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)
    Set wrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wdDoc = wrd.Documents.Open(wdFileName) 'open PDF file in Word
    wrd.Visible = False

    wrd.Selection.WholeStory
    wrd.Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text" 'optional - pastes whole document for easy checking
    Range("A1").Select

    With wdDoc
        TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
        If TableNo = 0 Then MsgBox "This document contains no tables", vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"

        For iCount = 1 To TableNo
            Worksheets.Add
            'Range("A:M").NumberFormat = "@"
            TableNo = iCount
            With .tables(TableNo)
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
                For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                    For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                        On Error Resume Next
                        Cells(iRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                    Next iCol
                Next iRow
            End With
        Next iCount
    End With

    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    wrd.Quit
    Set wrd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hope this is of use.

EDIT:  Almost forgot the last part of your query.
importhtml is not an Excel formula/function I am familiar with.  It may be that you have seen a custom function someone has created?  I believe Google Sheets does have a formula name importhtml but I rarely use that software.